# my program won't execute anything after the while loop

Tags: java

I wrote this "calculator" and I want it to output the result after calculation but it won't for some reason !!
**A sample input would be**
2
1 + 1 * 2 =

**And output will be** 
4

Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=input.nextInt();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int result=input.nextInt();
        String operand=input.next();
        int flag=0;
        while (flag==0){
            int temp=input.nextInt();
            if (operand.equals("*"))
                result*=temp;
            else if (operand.equals("/"))
                result/=temp;
            else if (operand.equals("+"))
                result+=temp;
            else if (operand.equals("-"))
                result-=temp;
            else if (operand.equals("=")){
                flag=1;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            operand=input.next();
        }
    }

}

  }

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         int n=input.nextInt();
         for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             int result=input.nextInt();
             String operand=input.next();
             int flag=0;
             while (flag==0)
             {
                 int temp=input.nextInt();
                 if (operand.equals("*"))
                     result*=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("/"))
                     result/=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("+"))
                     result+=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("-"))
                     result-=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("="))
                 {
                     flag=1;
                     System.out.println(result);
                 }
            operand=input.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `nextLine()` to read the next line?

Comment: I don't want 'nextLine()' because I'm reading every single integer on its own

Comment: You need to renew your operator like you do your int. otherwise the operator will never change and unless you put = for your first one, it will stay in the while loop indefenantly.  use my answer below to  correct this

Comment: Please tag it as Homework then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control is waiting for input at the following line

```
    while (flag==0){
        int temp=input.nextInt(); <- its waiting for input after you enter =
```

Answer (score 0):

you are never inputting anything after you enter the while loop.  run a

```
operand=input.next();
```

again right before your closing bracket on your while loop.

otherwise your 1 + 1 * 2 = will read as 1+1+2 (never updating your operator)

```
while (flag==0)
        {
        int temp=input.nextInt();
        if (operand.equals("*"))
            result*=temp;
        else if (operand.equals("/"))
            result/=temp;
        else if (operand.equals("+"))
            result+=temp;
        else if (operand.equals("-"))
            result-=temp;
        else if (operand.equals("="))
             {
             flag=1;
             System.out.println(result);
             }
        operand=input.next();// needs to be inside closing bracket

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         int n=input.nextInt();
         for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             int result=input.nextInt();
             String operand=input.next();
             int flag=0;
             while (flag==0)
             {
                 int temp=input.nextInt();
                 if (operand.equals("*"))
                     result*=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("/"))
                     result/=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("+"))
                     result+=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("-"))
                     result-=temp;
                 else if (operand.equals("="))
                 {
                     flag=1;
                     System.out.println(result);
                 }
            operand=input.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why should I input it again ? I am already inputting the operand in the end of the loop

Comment: @user1504032 since it was homework I didn't want to point it out directly, but I updated my answer to show your error (commented)

Comment: It is inside the closing bracket of the while loop, you missed the closing bracket of the loop

Comment: I formated your answer (and showed it in mine) so we can see it better.  After seeing that it is inside the closing bracket, the only thing i can see is you should store the string in a buffer, because input is wating for an input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example to test : 1 + 1 =

first iteration :

```
 int result=input.nextInt();  //===> (1) + 1 =
 String operand=input.next();  //===> 1 (+) 1 =
 int temp=input.nextInt(); //===> 1 + (1) =
 result+=temp;  //===> result == 2
 operand=input.next(); //===> 1 + 1 (=)
```

second iteration :

```
 int temp=input.nextInt(); //===> ooops nothing to read : wait for a user input!
```

Here is an adapted version of your algorithm that should works :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=input.nextInt();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
      int result=input.nextInt();
      String operand=input.next();
      while (true){
        if (operand.equals("=")) {
          System.out.println(result);
          break;
        } else {
          int temp=input.nextInt();
          if (operand.equals("*"))
            result*=temp;
          else if (operand.equals("/"))
            result/=temp;
          else if (operand.equals("+"))
            result+=temp;
          else if (operand.equals("-"))
            result-=temp;
          operand=input.next();
        }
      }
    }
```

}

}